# What Python libraries to use in Data Pipeline?

Tags: python, database, etl, libraries, data-pipeline

I have a .csv in PowerBI and I need to automate a process to do daily
uploads to BigQuery. First of all, what python libraries should I keep in mind to develop a project like this, I don´t know where to look. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], including [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I have built an ETL pipeline and as far as I am concerned the most required libraries would be Pandas df and NumPy since you have mentioned that you are using .csv in power BI to upload to BigQuery,I would prefer pandas df.You can have a look at necessity of pandas df using this link:https://medium.com/@dhanush24shet/introduction-to-pandas-dataframes-for-absolute-beginners-part-1-3c4dc70a93d6.
Hope this helps you.